# What is the maximum string size or string length for ObjectSetText in MQL4?

Tags: string, object, mql4, truncation

```
Comment(MSGARRAY[0], "\n" , 
MSGARRAY[01], "\n" , 
MSGARRAY[02] , "\n" , 
" error:" , err, "\n" ,   
"") ;
```

does not truncate strings(see yellow text upper left in chart below) but

```
  ObjectCreate(tLabel,23,0,Time[0],PRICE_CLOSE);
  ObjectSet(tLabel, OBJPROP_CORNER, myCorner );
  ObjectSet(tLabel,OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,xPos);
  ObjectSet(tLabel,OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,yPos);
  ObjectSetText(tLabel,name,myFontSize,myFont,Color);
```

truncates.

What am I doing wrong/not doing right?

Thanks

**EDIT:
I am reading text from a file and that's where the truncation is happening.**

```
int h = FileOpen(FileName, FILE_TXT|FILE_READ); 

if(h != INVALID_HANDLE) 
{ 

Comment("File "+FileName+" not found in MQL FILES FOLDER."); 

for (int c=0; !FileIsEnding(h) && c<9999; c++) 
{ 
     if (FileIsEnding(h)) break; 

     MSGARRAY[c]=FileReadString(h); 
} 

     FileClose(h); 
} 
else 
{ 
     Comment(FileName +" not found in MQL FILES FOLDER. OR... File Must Be Open..."); 

}
```

[image: code output]

Answer (score 0):

The maximum text length for text as an object is 63 characters. You can see this using the following code:

```
   string id="test";
   ObjectCreate    (0, id, OBJ_LABEL, 0, 0, 0);
   ObjectSet       (id, OBJPROP_CORNER, 0);
   ObjectSet       (id, OBJPROP_XDISTANCE, 10);
   ObjectSet       (id, OBJPROP_YDISTANCE, 10);
   ObjectSetText   (id, "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345", 10, "Arial", clrBlack);
```

The solution is to use two objects, and you can use `TextGetSize()` to find the offset for the second object.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I am reading from a TXT file, not from an object.  Where in the MQL4 documentation is maximum string length defined?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you are reading from. Both object names and text are limited to 63 characters. Whilst it is not specifically defined in the documentation, the above example shows this is the case. Check [this page of the documentation](https://docs.mql4.com/objects/objectcreate) which refers to object name limits.